# Prevent handleRequest from connecting to database in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm running Symfony2 on localhost and disabled any access to the internet.

I'm trying to develop without depending on a database. However when I try to get the values from a form using `handleRequest()` it's trying to use my original MySQL config to connect to the database for whatever reason.

I looked at the stack trance and `handleRequest()` shouldn't need access to the database. Why is it trying to connect and giving me the error `can't connect to MySQL server`? I'm only submitting data to a form.

What I've done for now is use an empty `try/catch`

```
try {
    $Form->handleRequest($request);
} catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e) {
}

if ($Form->isValid()) {
//do something
}
```

The above allows me to submit and validate the form. Duplicating the `try/catch` code for every form I try to validate seems unnecessary.

Is there something I'm missing?

Here's the stack trace:

[image]

Comment: Are you still loading doctrine?  That error message implies you listed MySQL as your database driver and i think you need to make sure you do not load doctrine as part of your app.

Comment: @George I did list MySQL as my database driver. However I don't need it loaded unless I need to use it.

Comment: However, dbal connects on demand. Somewhere your application need to connect. What about the constraints of the form?

Comment: @Leggendario I don't have any constraints that need to access the database. Not even custom ones. It's only one `Country` choice list field with a `NotBlank` constraint.

Comment: Can you give us the whole stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @Leggendario I edited the question with the stack trace now.

Comment: Just for grins, disable the profile debug bar or just test your app in production mode.  I think I ran into a similar case where is was really the profiler trying to get some database stats.

Comment: I still think that you're using a constraint like UniqueEntity. Can you check if you miss some YAML/Annotations/XML/loadValidatorMetadata method with that Constraints?

Comment: In order to find out why is it trying to connect to DB, I would put a breakpoint at line `Connection:getDatabasePlatform()` . Once it hits, you should not have any problem backtracking it to the concrete source of invocation.

Comment: Do you have `data_class` set on your form?  Remove that if it is

Comment: Can you clear your dev log and try submitting the form in dev mode, then looking at your log?  You may get more error messages that as long as logging is enabled and I found that to be more useful to spot errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Doctrine DBAL 2.5 (released in December 2014), for certain database drivers like MySQL, it will eagerly connect to the server to determine the server version. This probably can be considered a bug, and there is an [open ticket](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-1057) for it, and more background information in [this thread](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/487).

Currently, a fix or a workaround is to specify the MySQL server version in your connection configuration in `app/config/config.yml`. You should specify the appropriate version depending on your MySQL server, probably 5.5 or 5.6.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                # connection parameters ...
                server_version: 5.6
```

Comment: Yep, this is it. I hope it can be fixed soon.